# Getting the current page in plain TeX

Tags: page-numbering, plain-tex

What was the control sequence to get the current page in plain TeX? I thought it was `\thepage`, and this works in LaTeX, but it returns a undefined-control-sequence error in plain TeX.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\number\pageno
```

Third dangerous bend  sign on page 252 of the TeXbook:

> The page number appears in TeX’s internal register `\count0`, as
>   explained in Chapter 15, and plain TeX makes `\pageno` an abbreviation
>   for `\count0`. Thus you can say `\pageno=100` if you want the next page
>   of your output to be number `100`. The `\folio` macro converts negative
>   page numbers to roman numerals; if your manuscript begins with
>   `\pageno=-1`, the pages will be numbered i, ii, iii, iv, v, etc. In
>   fact, Appendix B defines `\folio` to be an abbreviation for
>   `\ifnum\pageno<0 \romannumeral-\pageno \else\number\pageno \fi`